# Why cant i call a function onmousemove?

Tags: javascript, function, call

Here's the simplified code, it should get the coordinates of the mouse when it moves.

The JavaScript:

```
document.body.onmousemove = move;

function move (e) {
    var xyz  = document.getElementById("coord");
    x = e.clientX ;
    y = e.clientY ;
    xyz.innerHTML = x +" "+ y ;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="coord"></div>
```

It works well on CodePen but not on a website.

Comment: you're calling the move function with () and assigning the result, when i imagine what you want is to assign the function itself. so remove the () from the assignment

Comment: it worked on codepen without "()" but it doesnt work on a website

Comment: Show enough of your [MCVE] code that we can reproduce your problem, then we may be able to offer useful advice for you, and those that see the question later.

Comment: document.body.onmousemove = move; should do the job

Comment: Where did you define the move function?

Comment: *"it worked on codepen without "()" but it doesnt work on a website"* We can't help you without a [mcve].

Comment: just updated the code

Answer (score 1):

```js
function move(e) {
  alert("mouse movement detected!");
}
document.onmousemove = move;
```